# Shipping charges are not working

Tags: shipping, soap, android

**Edit**

After I used below answer, now i am getting shipping charges in App.

But we are facing some small issue now:

**Based on distance, we have set the shipping price,**

```
Shipping A : less than 100 kms = 50 $ , 
shipping B : 100 to 200 kms     100 $ 
shipping c : 200 and above kms-  150 $
```

now we are getting only **"shipping c"**  charges [150$] for all distances. before we were getting all shipping A, B, C charges correctly in site.....

**Edit End**

app/code/local/company/extension/Model/Carrier/Localdelivery.php

```
<?php
class Webkul_Mpperproductshipping_Model_Carrier_LocalDelivery extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
{
    /* Use group alias */
    protected $_code = 'mpperproductshipping';
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){
        //skip if not enabled
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')||Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/mp_multi_shipping/active')){
           return false;
        }

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $postcode=$session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
        $countrycode=$session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountry();
        $postcode=str_replace('-', '', $postcode);
        $shippingdetail=array();
        $shippostaldetail=array('countrycode'=>$countrycode,'postalcode'=>$postcode);
        /****/
        foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $proid=$item->getProductId();
            $options=$item->getProductOptions();
            $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
            if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                    $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                    if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                        $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $mpassignModel = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
                $partner = $mpassignModel->getSellerId();
            } else {
                $collection=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')
                    ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$proid));
                foreach($collection as $temp) {
                    $partner=$temp->getUserid();
                }
            }

            $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid)->getWeight();
            $weight=$product*$item->getQty();
            if(count($shippingdetail)==0){
                array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
            }else{
                $shipinfoflag=true;
                $index=0;
                foreach($shippingdetail as $itemship){
                    if($itemship['seller_id']==$partner){
                        $itemship['items_weight']=$itemship['items_weight']+$weight;
                        $itemship['product_name']=$itemship['product_name'].",".$item->getName();
                        $itemship['item_id']=$itemship['item_id'].",".$item->getId();
                        $itemship['qty']=$itemship['qty']+$item->getQty();
                        $shippingdetail[$index]=$itemship;
                        $shipinfoflag=false;
                    }
                    $index++;
                }
                if($shipinfoflag==true){
                    array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
                }
            }
        }
        $shippingpricedetail=$this->getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail);

        if($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']!==""){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingCustomError($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']);
            return $result;
        }
        /*store shipping in session*/
        $shippingAll=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('shippinginfo');
        $shippingAll[$this->_code]=$shippingpricedetail['shippinginfo'];
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('shippinginfo',$shippingAll);

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'));
        /* Use method name */
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/name'));
        $method->setCost($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']);
        $method->setPrice($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']); 
        $result->append($method);
        return $result; 
    }

     public function getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail) {
        $shippinginfo=array();
        $handling=0;
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $customerAddress = $session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
        foreach($shippingdetail as $shipdetail) {
            $seller = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($shipdetail['seller_id']);
            $sellerAddress = $seller->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            $distance = $this->getDistanse($sellerAddress->getPostcode(),$customerAddress->getPostcode());
            $price = 0;
            $itemsarray=explode(',',$shipdetail['item_id']);
            foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $proid=$item->getProductId();
                $options=$item->getProductOptions();
                $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
                if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                    foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                        $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                        if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                            $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                        }
                    }
                }
                $mpshippingcharge = 0;
                $localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
                $regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
                $stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');
                if(in_array($item->getId(),$itemsarray)) {
                    if($mpassignproductId) {
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getLocalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getStateShippingCharge();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpLocalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpStateShippingCharge();
                        }   
                    }
                    if(floatval($mpshippingcharge)==0){
                        $price=$price+floatval($this->getConfigData('defalt_ship_amount'));
                    }else{
                        $price=$price+$mpshippingcharge;
                    }
                }
            }

            $handling = $handling+$price;
            $submethod = array(array('method'=>Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'),'cost'=>$price,'error'=>0));
            array_push($shippinginfo,array('seller_id'=>$shipdetail['seller_id'],'methodcode'=>$this->_code,'shipping_ammount'=>$price,'product_name'=>$shipdetail['product_name'],'submethod'=>$submethod,'item_ids'=>$shipdetail['item_id']));
        }
        $msg="";
        return array('handlingfee'=>$handling,'shippinginfo'=>$shippinginfo,'errormsg'=>$msg);
    }

    private function getDistanse($origin,$destination) {
        $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$origin.",india&destinations=".$destination.",india&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response_all = json_decode($response);
        $distance = $response_all->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value / 1000;
        return $distance;
    }
}
```

we have marketplace **multi vendor/seller** site. we are doing Android App for the site....

we are using custom Shipping method  in our site.

This shipping method is based on "**seller" & "Buyer**" **zip** code. we save seller zip code in Backend. we set the how much shipping charges according to distance in Backend. Once Buyer enter the zip code in shipping address , it will calculate the  shipping charges between seller and buyer based on distance.

This is working fine in site.

But in Android app, we are calling this API to get shipping methods : **shoppingCartShippingList()**

we are getting shipping method , **but we are getting shipping charges as zero.**

Above i posted extension code responsible for getting shipping charges....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem may be related to an incorrect use of quote data. Don't instantiate the `checkout/session` model in `collectRates()` method because it may start a new session when you call an API method. Collect the customer's shipping address data from `$request` object (the instance of Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request). Try these methods instead of yours:

- `$session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode()`
  replace with
  `$request->getDestPostcode()`
- `$session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountry()`
  replace with
  `$request->getDestCountryId()` or `$request->getDestCountry()`
- `$session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()` 
  replace with
  `$request->getAllItems()`

Check how it is used in `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Dhl::collectRates()`.

**EDIT**

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){
        //skip if not enabled
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')||Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/mp_multi_shipping/active')){
           return false;
        }

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

        /* Edited by martin_mageworx */
        $postcode=$request->getDestPostcode();
        $countrycode=$request->getDestCountry();
        $items=$request->getAllItems();
        /* End Editing by martin_mageworx */

        $postcode=str_replace('-', '', $postcode);
        $shippingdetail=array();
        $shippostaldetail=array('countrycode'=>$countrycode,'postalcode'=>$postcode,'items'=>$items);
        /****/
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $proid=$item->getProductId();
            $options=$item->getProductOptions();
            $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
            if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                    $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                    if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                        $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $mpassignModel = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
                $partner = $mpassignModel->getSellerId();
            } else {
                $collection=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')
                    ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$proid));
                foreach($collection as $temp) {
                    $partner=$temp->getUserid();
                }
            }

            $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid)->getWeight();
            $weight=$product*$item->getQty();
            if(count($shippingdetail)==0){
                array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
            }else{
                $shipinfoflag=true;
                $index=0;
                foreach($shippingdetail as $itemship){
                    if($itemship['seller_id']==$partner){
                        $itemship['items_weight']=$itemship['items_weight']+$weight;
                        $itemship['product_name']=$itemship['product_name'].",".$item->getName();
                        $itemship['item_id']=$itemship['item_id'].",".$item->getId();
                        $itemship['qty']=$itemship['qty']+$item->getQty();
                        $shippingdetail[$index]=$itemship;
                        $shipinfoflag=false;
                    }
                    $index++;
                }
                if($shipinfoflag==true){
                    array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
                }
            }
        }
        $shippingpricedetail=$this->getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail);

        if($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']!==""){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingCustomError($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']);
            return $result;
        }
        /*store shipping in session*/
        $shippingAll=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('shippinginfo');
        $shippingAll[$this->_code]=$shippingpricedetail['shippinginfo'];
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('shippinginfo',$shippingAll);

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'));
        /* Use method name */
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/name'));
        $method->setCost($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']);
        $method->setPrice($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']); 
        $result->append($method);
        return $result; 
    }

public function getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail) {
        $shippinginfo=array();
        $handling=0;
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $customerAddress = $session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

        /* Edited by martin_mageworx */
        $customerPostCode = $shippostaldetail['postalcode'];
        $items = $shippostaldetail['items'];
        /* End Editing by martin_mageworx */

        foreach($shippingdetail as $shipdetail) {
            $seller = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($shipdetail['seller_id']);
            $sellerAddress = $seller->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            $distance = $this->getDistanse($sellerAddress->getPostcode(),$customerPostCode);
            $price = 0;
            $itemsarray=explode(',',$shipdetail['item_id']);
            foreach($items as $item) {
                $proid=$item->getProductId();
                $options=$item->getProductOptions();
                $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
                if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                    foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                        $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                        if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                            $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                        }
                    }
                }
                $mpshippingcharge = 0;
                $localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
                $regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
                $stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');
                if(in_array($item->getId(),$itemsarray)) {
                    if($mpassignproductId) {
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getLocalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getStateShippingCharge();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpLocalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpStateShippingCharge();
                        }   
                    }
                    if(floatval($mpshippingcharge)==0){
                        $price=$price+floatval($this->getConfigData('defalt_ship_amount'));
                    }else{
                        $price=$price+$mpshippingcharge;
                    }
                }
            }

            $handling = $handling+$price;
            $submethod = array(array('method'=>Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'),'cost'=>$price,'error'=>0));
            array_push($shippinginfo,array('seller_id'=>$shipdetail['seller_id'],'methodcode'=>$this->_code,'shipping_ammount'=>$price,'product_name'=>$shipdetail['product_name'],'submethod'=>$submethod,'item_ids'=>$shipdetail['item_id']));
        }
        $msg="";
        return array('handlingfee'=>$handling,'shippinginfo'=>$shippinginfo,'errormsg'=>$msg);
    }
```

Comment: i changed those 3 lines of codes, still same result.... please check is there anything else i have to do ?

Comment: In getShippingPricedetail() you also have an instance of checkout/session model. Did you replace it too?

Comment: no, please help what i have to replace there ?

Comment: You use checkout/session model in getShippingPricedetail() just for getting customer's post code. Don't use checkout/session here and use $shippostaldetail parameter, because it is not used at all.

Comment: getShippingPriceDetail function = http://pastebin.com/jdnqrU43  can you please give updated code for this.

Comment: please give the code as you said in above function.....

Comment: instead  of this line : $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session'); , what i need to replace ?

Comment: please update the answer with full code.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please note, that I didn't refactor the methods, I've just placed items to $shippostaldetail variable

Comment: i am checking, i  iwill let you know about the result:-)

Comment: can you please refactor method also and update the code. because now we are getting only one type of shipping charges in site 

before we had 3 types of shipping charges. but good thing is we are getting shipping charges in app.

Comment: means based on zip code, we have set the distance,

Shipping A : less than 100 kms = 50 $

shipping B : 100 to 200 kms = 100 $

shipping c : 200 and above - 150 $

now we are getting only "shipping c". before we were getting all shipping A, B, C.....

Comment: I have no free time yet to make a refactoring. In spite of that it can't be done having only a piece of code without all other related classes. Furthermore the provided idea helped you to solve the main problem you asked. I think that the solution may be marked as resolved. I hope you understand me right.

Comment: sure, for sure i will mark it as solution , once i solve this issse i i will do that.

Comment: please check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97220/shipping-charges-working-in-app-but-not-working-according-to-the-distance once you get time.

Comment: See my answer there. Hope it will be helpful too. If it works I'll edit the current answer

Comment: please update the answer in that link .

Comment: I will tell you, Believe me  You are going to be the SUPERSTAR in Magento..... You saved my life.